# Tosca - Java Exception while running Swing Application (JTree)

Tags: tosca

I am learning tosca and currently we are trying to run a regression test suite for a legacy Java Swing application.

My Test suite contains 4 modules (in `JTree`) and it is getting failed while clicking a node.

The Error I received on the module is,

> at.tosca.javaengine.common.exceptions.ControlException: node or
>   node-path not found!
>  Detailed information contained in
>   'JavaEngineException.txt 
> above message is displayed in Executionlist

**JavaEngineException.txt**

> 22-11-2017 - 17:56:37: IExecWrapperInterface_connectToControl
>   at.tosca.javaengine.common.exceptions.ControlNotFoundException: Unable
>   to find control Index=3;ClassName(s)=[javax.swing.JTable];.
>
> at.tosca.javaengine.server.tree.ComponentSearch.getComponent(ComponentSearch.java:218)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.AbstractJavaEngineCore.findComponent(AbstractJavaEngineCore.java:1129)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.AbstractJavaEngineCore.connectToControlInternal(AbstractJavaEngineCore.java:936)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.AbstractJavaEngineCore.connectToControlInternal(AbstractJavaEngineCore.java:922)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.AbstractJavaEngineCore.connectToControl(AbstractJavaEngineCore.java:313)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.JavaEngineCore.access$101(JavaEngineCore.java:25)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.JavaEngineCore$2.runInternal(JavaEngineCore.java:69)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.control.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:69)
>   ->java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ->JNIServer::CallVoidMethod
>   ->CJNIServer::CallVoidMethod
>
> 22-11-2017 - 17:58:58: IExecWrapperInterface_setValue
>   at.tosca.javaengine.common.exceptions.ControlException: node or
>   node-path not found!
>
> at.tosca.javaengine.server.control.swing.GenericTreeControl.setValueLegacy(GenericTreeControl.java:339)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.control.swing.GenericTreeControl.setValue(GenericTreeControl.java:88)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.AbstractJavaEngineCore.setValueInternal(AbstractJavaEngineCore.java:1195)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.AbstractJavaEngineCore.setValue(AbstractJavaEngineCore.java:686)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.JavaEngineCore.access$401(JavaEngineCore.java:25)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.JavaEngineCore$5.runInternal(JavaEngineCore.java:114)
>   ->at.tosca.javaengine.server.control.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:69)
>   ->java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ->JNIServer::CallVoidMethod
>   ->CJNIServer::CallVoidMethod

**NOTE** : The same Test suite is working in some other machine and not here. Both are same operating System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was TOSCA is faster than our application :)

**Meaning:** The frame was not loaded at the time when TOSCA was trying to scan the next page causing the error, the specific node was
 not found.

**Solution:** I added a `TBoxWait` with extra seconds, after that this is working fine.

Comment: I would suggest using a WaitOn with a condition of Exist == True to verify a specific object is loaded (if possible). That way Tosca will continue execution immediately after the object is found instead of waiting an arbitrary, hard coded amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing.
Looks like you are connecting to a JTable and then trying to select a node? Are you sure Tosca is finding the correct control on both machines? (Index=3 does not sound like a stable identification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, But I am not sure then how it is working in one machine and not in another. Well regarding the logs, thats what all I have got. Is there any way to explore more on this problem to identify the root cause?